# Xcode IDE layout not showing the ViewController connections together with the Main.storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode

I have lost the `ViewController` connections for the `Main.storyboard` - and the `Xcode` Menu items seem to be oblivious to this. Which of the icons will bring it back?

[image]

**Update** the image was updated to include the icons on the far right

**Another update** @matt basically solved this by saying `Command-Alt-7` to show the connections.

[image]

Comment: Could I prevail upon you to ask _one_ question, please?

Comment: What do you mean *"lost the `ViewController` connections"*? Do you mean you don't see the arrows? Do you see them if you scroll up and down or reduce the magnification level?

Comment: OK so are we talking about the Connections Inspector that would be on the right? If so, that's Command-Option-7. There is an icon you can tap, too, but you have cut it out of your screen shot.

Comment: @matt  Yes that's what I was looking for. Saved by you again: pls make an answer.  Where are you finding these shortcuts?  Even `CheatSheet` does not list that one.

Comment: I looked in my book. :) The keyboard command should be View > Utilities > Show Connections Inspector, by the way.

Comment: @matt  If I do another iOS project ( 1 ) heaven help us ( 2 ) i'll buy your book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not prevail on the eminent @matt to make his comment an answer: so here it is in my approximate words.

> The Connections Inspector is `Command-Option-7`.

Also

- keyboard command is `View > Utilities > Show Connections Inspector`
- The icon is in the bottom right